# html <a name> attribute not working

Tags: html, attributes, anchor

To be able to jump to a certain table row, I add an attribute before each table row. however, I cannot jump to the table row, when adding a

```
http://server/test.php#row-92
```

to my url. The table row is built like that

```
<a name="row-92"></a><tr onclick="document.location ..... </tr>
```

Comment: The <a> name attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use the id attribute instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the id-attribute. Starting with HTML5 the a-name tag is deprecated.

`<tr id="row-97" onclick="document.location ..... </tr>`